# C# NHibernate Substring Method Not Found

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I'm trying to run a query on a list of contacts and filter them using a given String filter. Code as follows:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<CrmContact>()
                .Where(x => x.Account.ID == account.ID && x.IsActive && x.IsContact);    

query.And(Restrictions.Disjunction()
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.FirstName), filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.LastName), filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Email), filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Company), filtString))
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Phone.Substring(0, 3)), filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Phone.Substring(3, 3)), filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
  .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Phone.Substring(6, 4)), filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere)));
```

However, I am running into a problem with the last 3 statements, as I am getting a "Method Substring not found" error when running them. I am using substring to try and match the separate parts of a phone number in the case of a filter being a phone number/part of one (e.g. "123" would match "1234567890" but not "0123456789" as that would span the two parts).

Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you can't use `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`, or `Contains`, you'll likely need a custom function that adapts the method call into sql for you.  example: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/adding-custom-sql-functions-to-nhibernate-at-runtime

Comment: check datatypes etc in your IDE; in any case you need to provide some more information for a proper solution to be provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SubString` in a lambda is right with [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate), but not with [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover). You are using [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover), avoid using [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) syntax or use Linq instead of QueryOver.

Linq (case insensitivity of `Contains` and `==` depends on your db, you may remove `ToUpper` calls if your db is already case insensitive):

```
using System.Linq;
using NHibernate.Linq;

// ...

filtString = filtString.ToUpper();
var query = Session.Query<CrmContact>()
    .Where(x => x.Account.ID == account.ID && x.IsActive && x.IsContact)
    .Where(c => c.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(filtString) ||
        c.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(filtString) ||
        c.Email.ToUpper().Contains(filtString) ||
        c.Company.ToUpper() == filtString ||
        c.Phone.ToUpper().Substring(0, 3).Contains(filtString) ||
        c.Phone.ToUpper().Substring(3, 3).Contains(filtString) ||
        c.Phone.ToUpper().Substring(6, 4).Contains(filtString));
```

QueryOver:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<CrmContact>()
    .Where(x => x.Account.ID == account.ID && x.IsActive && x.IsContact);    

query.And(Restrictions.Disjunction()
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.FirstName),
        filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.LastName),
        filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Email),
        filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(Projections.Property<CrmContact>(c => c.Company),
        filtString))
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(
        Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String,
            Projections.Property<DimServicePoint>(c => c.Phone),
            Projections.Constant(0), Projections.Constant(3)),
        filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(
        Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String,
            Projections.Property<DimServicePoint>(c => c.Phone),
            Projections.Constant(3), Projections.Constant(3)),
        filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere))
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(
        Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String,
            Projections.Property<DimServicePoint>(c => c.Phone),
            Projections.Constant(6), Projections.Constant(4)),
        filtString, MatchMode.Anywhere)));
```